# Connecting PDO to MS SQL Server 2008 R2 Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [53]

Tags: php, sql-server-2008, pdo, xampp

My PC has Installed MS SQL Server 2008 R2 with installed Database, Then I installed **XAMPP** and made another port for **Apache** to make it `localhost:8080` and listen to `4433`. Then Installed **OBDC**, Tried to connect using

```
try {
$host = 'LOCAL';
$user = '****';
$pass = '****';

$dsn = "sqlsrv:Server=$host;Database=$db;";
$opt = [
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
];
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $opt);

} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "No connection: " . $e->getMessage();
    exit;
}
```

But I keep getting

```
No connection: SQLSTATE[08001]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [53].
```

Used `extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_71_ts_x86.dll`

I've shutdown **Windows Firewall**, Enabled **Pipe Connection** in **MS SQL 2008 Configuration** and **Internet Option NetBIOS Enabeled**

Answer (score 1):

if you are using a local instance, the server string needs a double backslash:

```
<?php
$conn = new PDO('sqlsrv:Server=localhost\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=MyDatabase', 'MyUsername', 'MyPassword');
?>
```

See original provided answer by Daniel Klein: 
https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-sqlsrv.connection.php#121301

Answer (score 0):

`$host` shouldn't be `"LOCAL"` but `"localhost"`.

If you are running SQL server on a custom port on your local machine, you can specify the port by appending it with a comma to the host; applied to your code snippet:

```
$host = "localhost";
// or, with a custom port
$host = "localhost,12345"
```

Source: http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-sqlsrv.connection.php#refsect1-ref.pdo-sqlsrv.connection-examples